# I have installed a new package `@polkadot` after that I am getting the error

Tags: node-modules, babel-loader, react-scripts, unexpected-token

```
./node_modules/@polkadot/x-global/packageInfo.js 3:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export const packageInfo = {
|   name: '@polkadot/x-global',
>   path: import.meta && import.meta.url ? new URL(import.meta.url).pathname.substring(0, new URL(import.meta.url).pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) : 'auto',
|   type: 'esm',
|   version: '12.0.1'
```

Tried with updating the version of package and by removing the node_modules and yarn.lock file

tried with .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "es1015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "es2018",
    "es2019",
    "es2020",
    "es2021"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```